# How to find the smallest interval containing a set of values modulo N?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

First the practical application that led me to the problem:

Given a set of angle measurements `v[i]` in the range of [0,360) degrees,
what is the smallest interval containing all `v[i]?`

Note: the interval may be on both sides, close around 0.

Abstract description of the problem:

For a given set of values `v[i]`, what are the values `c` and `d`, such that

- for all `i`: `dist(v[i],c) <= d` and
- `d` is as small as possible and
- `dist(x,y) = abs(((x-y + N/2 + N) mod N) - N/2)` ?

This is trivial on an open (infinite) scale, where `dist(x,y) = abs(x-y)`:

```
calculate max and min of all v[i]
c = (max + min)/2;
d = (max - min)/2;
```

But what's the best way to find c and d for a finite scale (modulo N) and 
a distance defintion as given above?

Is there maybe a way to do it O(n) (if n is the number of values)?

Comment: What is v[i] - an integer? An ordered pair [start_degree, end_degree]?

Comment: v[i] is one measured value (integer or real doesn't matter). Lets suppose all values are stored in an array v.

Comment: What's the purpose? Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491738/how-do-you-calculate-the-average-of-a-set-of-angles/491769 is relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, how about following:

1. normalize all angles to [0, N)
2. sort angles (minimum first)
3. find neigborung pair with maximum distance:
   3.1 You need always subtract (next - previous)
   3.2 The last pair should be (last; first + N)
4. think that pair is what you need - only use opposite angle to that you found in step 3.

Am I wrong? In other words my solution is obvious -- you just find the biggest part of the pie and eat it :) all that left - is what you need.

Comment: Ok, slowly I think I get it. Maybe you could have described step 3 better: "find neigborung pair...". That's why you sorted in step 2.
Then, yes, it actually becomes obvious.

Comment: Sorry, I not good enough to express my thought in english freely :)
However -- some bottlenecks -- i lied you can't using Tom Ritter's dist in this algorithm. (1) You need always subtract (next - previous) (2) the last pair should be (last; first + N)

Comment: I believe that if you had this set: { 1, 3, 359 }, your algorithm would return [1, 359] as the smallest interval, where it should be [359, 3].

Comment: Why? We have cycling through zero -- thus [359; 3] - is 4 degrees, and [1; 359] - only two - it's smaller. There will be no challenge without cycling :)

Comment: But [1, 359] doesn't include 3 :)

Comment: My algo returns [359, 3], i've checked it :)

Comment: I understood -- statment about dist confused you, however in comments i said that you should use other way... so I'll edit answer better.

Comment: +1, This is a very elegant solution, and "find the biggest part of the pie and eat it" is an excellent description. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have an own solution, however, I am not quite satisfied with it as it assumes that d will never be larger than N/4:

```
if(v[0]>=N/4 && v[0]<(3*N)/4)
{
  calculate min and max of all v[i]
  c = (max + min)/2;   
  d = (max - min)/2;
}
else
{
  calculate min and max of all (v[i] + N/2) % N
  c = ((max + min)/2 - N/2; 
  d = ((max - min)/2 - N/2;
}
```

Any better solution, especially one that would work also if d turns out to be > N/4?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems equivalent to finding the maximum distance between two of your angles.

You should just be able to iterate through your v set, compute the distance between each element, then find the largest distance.

You might try something like this for your distance function:

```
void dist_mod_360(int a, int b)
{
    const int n = 360; 
    return min((a - b) % n, (b - a) % n);
}
```

Comment: No. My distance function is fine and it works perfectly (also close to 0 and 360). What I am looking for is a good (ideally O(n)) algorithm to find c and d.

Comment: Guess you mean "compute the distance between each _pair_ of elements". Ok. This is about what Mihail proposed. This, however, takes O(n*(n-1)) (if n is the number of values).

Answer (score 0):

```
angle = max(v) - min(v)
return angle if angle <=180 else 360 - angle # to get the smallest absolute value
```