# Average of 2 angles with 360 degrees wrap around

Tags: erlang, geometry, trigonometry

The top answer in [Average of two angles with wrap around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158909/average-of-two-angles-with-wrap-around) is wrong per testing + the comments.

The bottom answer 12>

```
 math:atan(  (math:sin(180)+math:sin(270)) / (math:cos(180)+math:cos(270))).
-1.1946710584651132
```

but I get -1.946.. instead of the expected  225.

Erlang's `math:atan` isn't behaving according to http://rapidtables.com/calc/math/Arctan_Calculator.htm , however, which gives different results .

How do I find the average of 2 angles in a circle?

Edit: Attempting to use Radians.
Degrees are 180 and 270.

```
16> A = 180 * 3.14 / 180.
3.14
17> B = 270 * 3.14 / 180.
4.71
18> S = math:sin(A) + math:sin(B).
-0.9984044934712312
19> S2 = S / 2.
-0.4992022467356156
20> C = math:cos(A) + math:cos(B).
-1.002387709839821
21> C2 = C / 2.
-0.5011938549199105
22> math:atan(S, C).
** exception error: undefined function math:atan/2
23> math:atan(S/C).
0.7834073464102068
24> math:atan(S/C) * 180 / 3.14.
44.90870138657236
25> math:atan(S2/C2) * 180 / 3.14.
44.90870138657236
```

Conversion:
-1.19 to degrees = -68.18198.3 360 - 68 = 292. This isn't the expected 225.

Comment: Try using radians.

Comment: I tried using Radians, please see edit

Comment: use `math:atan2(S,C)` this will put the angle on the correct quadrant.

Comment: That gives math:atan2(S, C).
3.1288514248714483 . ~178 degrees

Comment: In your code above `S=-0.9984044934712312` and `C=-1.002387709839821`. `atan2(S,C)=-2.35818` which is -135 degrees. -135+360=225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<cos(t), sin(t)>` is the unit vector with angle `t` **in radians**. So your formula adds the two unit vectors and and then finds the angle of the resultant vector.

Just use radians instead of degrees and use `atan2` instead of `atan` (which puts the angle on the correct  quadrant) and you should see your formula works correctly.

`math:atan2(  math:sin(t1)+math:sin(t2),
 math:cos(t1)+math:cos(t2))`

Where this formula does not work is if the two angles are precisely 180 degrees apart from each other. In this case the resultant vector is the zero vector and `atan` is undefined.

Comment: math:atan2(  math:sin(180)+math:sin(270),
29>  math:cos(180)+math:cos(270)).
-1.1946710584651132.

I'm trying to get an answer in degrees.

Comment: Yeah. You need to use radians and you need to use atan2. You can convert back to degrees when done.

Comment: @quantumpotato if this works for you please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Please see my edit of the original question "conversion". I tried what you suggested in comments. Please use my sample code and edit your answer if you have the working answer

Comment: @quantumpotato 180 deg = pi radians. 270 deg = 3pi/2 radians. sin(pi)+sin(3pi/2) = -1.   cos(pi)+cos(3pi/2)=-1.  atan2(-1,-1)=5pi/4 radians or 225 deg.