# how to find mid point using in android?

Tags: android

how do you find a mid point using google maps API in android ? I want the mid point along the route. Something like if a person starts moving from point A and if we stop him at 50% of the total distance, then we can obtain the mid-point along the route. So, how to do it in android?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: are u using google map api 3??

Comment: You can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176555/midpoint-of-route-in-google-maps).It's in javascript.You can take the concept and convert it to java.Hope it helps.

Comment: @DerGolem yes, at first I tried it by calculating the total distance and dividing it by 2. But, the result is not right.

Comment: @setubasak no i am working on api 2