# Adding InfoWindow on Google directions route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow, directions, google-directions-api

I am trying to add an InfoWindow to directions route. there are lots of examples out there for adding InfoWindow on an event listener on a marker.

But how can I move the InfoWindow to show on the actual planned route from one marker to another. Someone already tried to ask this question before but no response ([InfoWindow on Directions Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521709/show-info-window-on-the-route-path-on-google-maps-api)).

Anyway I did a lot of googling and only found one question similar to this but than again there is no response to that.

I tried `infowindow.open(map,this)` on an event on marker in callback but it will open InfoWindow on marker position. Its just I want to show duration and distance similar like Google. Something like in the attached image

```
var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
distanceService.getDistanceMatrix(distanceRequest, function (response, status) {
    if (status == "OK") {
      infowindow2.setContent(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text + "<br>" + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text + " ")
    }
    else {
      alert("Error: " + status)
    }
  })
infowindow2.open(map, this);
```

[image: Google directions Image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps click event on route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902574/google-maps-click-event-on-route)

Comment: If you just want to open an infowindow on a point along the route (not on a click), all you need is a position to open it at.

Comment: Hi, how do i locate the position of a point on route  ?

Comment: parse the response from the directionsService.

Comment: you mean something like this infowindow2.open(map, response);

Comment: it has to be MVCObject that exposes a position-property

Comment: No.  I mean parse the directionsResponse like in my answer, get a location along the route and call the setPosition method of your infowindow with that position.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To find a position on a route and put an infoWindow there, parse the route ([the details are described in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults)).  Get a location along the route and call the setPosition method of your infowindow with that position.

```
function calcRoute(start, end) {
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var step = 1;
      var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      infowindow2.setContent(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].distance.text + "<br>" + response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].duration.text + " ");
      infowindow2.setPosition(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].end_location);
      infowindow2.open(map);
    }
  });
}
```

If you really need the midpoint of the route, see [Midpoint of route in google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176555/midpoint-of-route-in-google-maps)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vgLcd1p9/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute("67 The Windmill Hill, Allesley, Coventry CV5 9FR, UK", "26 Rosaville Crescent, Allesley, Coventry CV5 9BP, UK");
}

function calcRoute(start, end) {
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var step = Math.floor(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length / 2);
      var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      infowindow2.setContent(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].distance.text + "<br>" + response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].duration.text + " ");
      infowindow2.setPosition(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].end_location);
      infowindow2.open(map);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use overview_path array to find the center point of the path. And then set it as infowindow position.

```
var center_point = response.routes[0].overview_path.length/2;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow.setContent(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text + "<br>" + response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text + " ");
infowindow.setPosition(response.routes[0].overview_path[center_point|0]);
infowindow.open(map);
```

Comment: this is helpful, but this should be a comment