# averageCenter on markerclusterer

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I am using the google maps API to cluster markers.

For the moment the cluster center is set on the first marker added to it.
Is there a way to put it in the average of all locations?

I am using the google map API V2 in android.

thanks,

EDIT: on this website they are talking about an attribute to set "averageCenter" http://component.kitchen/components/timeu/google-map-markerclusterer

is there an equivalent for android ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the [Google Maps Android API utility library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) in your project, you can change the algorithm used for clustering.

The default algorithm used is the `NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm` (you can find the class file in `library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/`).

Now you can:

- either edit the source code of the  class,
- or create a new class extending `NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm` and overriding the `getClusters(double)` method. Then, use an instance of this class with your `ClusterManager` using `setAlgorithm(Algorithm)`.

The changes that need to be made in order to calculate the center position of clusters can be found in [this commit](https://github.com/tonymanou/android-maps-utils/commit/ca2ac61e7541c471b2cc57586bcc37cda98f2af0) (I chose to edit the class directly). *I did not measure the impact of these changes on the clustering calculation's speed though.*

---

**Edit:** currently, [a simple average is used](https://github.com/tonymanou/android-maps-utils/commit/ca2ac61e7541c471b2cc57586bcc37cda98f2af0#diff-2b8f9a99ba26dfc3a6cea2f425e69cc2R51) to calculate the cluster's position, which is incorrect for latitude/longitude coordinates but is a bit faster.

You can find a better center calculation algorithm here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14231286.