# How to extract images inside the bounding box using Instagram API?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, bounding-box

I'm trying to collect all images from a specific location, for example Tokyo. I manages to create a bounding box which gave me the following results

```
(50.607041876988994, -1.3187316344406208, 52.40735812301099, 1.5737316344406207)
```

Main problem is, what do I do next? What do each of these figure represent and how would I plot these if I were to use them for coding?

All I want is to use this bounding box and within it collect all images from Instagram. I was wondering if anyone can write a short pseudo code, or any language code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this stackoverflow answer you can calculate the center of bounding box: [Calculate the center point of multiple latitude/longitude coordinate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6671183/423089)

- which is `51.51608899635712, 0.09891956707558282`

You can then calculate distance between the center and corner of bounding box: [Function to calculate distance between two coordinates shows wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18883601/423089)

- which comes to about `141km`

using gramfeed, you can search instagram by location with a `lat,lng` and a `radius`, here are the resulting posts that are within the bounding box, it may have some extra posts outside the bounding box since instagram api searches within a circular area, if you want you can further filter the posts one by one for accuracy.

Here are the instagram posts within the bounding box:
http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map#/51.5165,0.0999/200/-

Comment: Thank you very much , very helpful :)

Comment: How did you get 51.51608899635712, 0.09891956707558282? because the structure of the code from the link you gave seemed very disorganised so i sorta modified it and i got (-1.4093883217883079, 0.6741482698408712)

Comment: i dont thinks thats right, it should be within the 2 values u have for bounding box