# calculate nearest latitude and longitude from two latitude and longitude in php

Tags: php, google-maps, latitude-longitude

Suppose I have lat1=21.154533 & long1=79.045760 with
accuracy of x meters, and another lat2=21.153184 & long2=79.045882. So can
I find out the nearest position (lat,long) with respect to lat1 &
long1 with the help of lat2 & long2 direction?

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671240/4471013)

Comment: This is unclear. What are you trying to find? The middle point between 2 points? Why do you need the direction if you already know point 1 and 2? What does the accuracy have to do with the placement of 1 point? Define "nearest position" - Nearest to what? Nearest by 1 km? 1 meter? 1 centimeter? 1 millimeter?

Comment: i am trying to find nearest coordinates from lat1, long1 because my lat2 & long2 where not accurate every time its an dynamic value with less accuracy which depend upon a device. so because of this scenario i am trying to find out coordinates from lat1 long1! (hope these will help to figure out )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found answer to my own question.

> - Calculate Bearing/Angle using Lat1,Long1 & Lat2,Long2

```
    function bearing($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2){
    $bearingradians = atan2(asin($long1-$long2)*cos($lat2),
    cos($lat1)*sin($lat2) - sin($lat1)*cos($lat2)*cos($long1-$long2)); 
    $bearingdegrees = abs(rad2deg($bearingradians));
    return $bearingdegrees;
    }
```

> - Calculate Distance between Lat1,Long1 & Lat2,Long2

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
      $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
      $dist = acos($dist);
      $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $distanceMeters = $dist * 60 * 1000;
     return $distanceMeters; 
    }
```

> - Then Generate New Lat Long near to Lat1,Long2.

```
$earthRadius = 6371000;
$lat1 = deg2rad(21.156845);
$lon1 = deg2rad(79.053331);
$lat2 = deg2rad(21.156805);
$lon2 = deg2rad(79.057634);

//$bearing = $this->bearing($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2); //you can get value from above function
//$distance = $this->distance($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2);//you can get value from above function
$bearing = deg2rad(90);
$distance =100;
$Newlat = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($distance / $earthRadius) + cos($lat1) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($bearing));
$Newlon = $lon1 + atan2(sin($bearing) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($lat1), cos($distance / $earthRadius) - sin($lat1) * sin($Newlat));
echo 'distance: ' .$distance;
echo 'bearing: ' .$bearing;
echo 'LAT: ' . rad2deg($Newlat);
echo 'LNG: ' . rad2deg($Newlon);
```

> The conclusion is if we get incorrect lat2,long2 values. But we can
>   exact calculate lat,long near lat1 and lat2 with its accurate angle. This challenge we found while integrate beacons technology.