# How to calculate mean and standard deviation for hue values from 0 to 360?

Tags: colors, statistics, hue

Suppose 5 samples of hue are taken using a simple HSV model for color, having values 355, 5, 5, 5, 5, all a hue of red and "next" to each other as far as perception is concerned.  But the simple average is 75 which is far away from 0 or 360, close to a yellow-green.

What is a better way to calculate this mean and associated std?

Comment: After considerably more digging around with Google, found a link back to stackoverflow from a post actually discussing average wind direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491738/how-do-you-calculate-the-average-of-a-set-of-angles/3651941#3651941  But it doesn't address the issue of standard deviation.

Comment: Once you've got a mean you're happy with, you can just calculate the standard deviation from the mean deviations, right?

Comment: @AakashM, I'm still trying to figure this out.  I know code. Statistics I'm a bit more hazy on.

Comment: On several websites where I see this question trying to be answered, I also see contrived data sets, such as two entries for 270 and 90, which then say that the average is meaningless.  In order to avoid this, here is a small sample of actual values with which I'm working: (naive mean and std are: 185.658 174.848)
347.059
0
359.059
347
354.05
353.012
13.012
358.118
8.06723
354.118
0.967742
0.97561
351.074
8.06324
346.098
0.941176
1.88235
355.082
6.93227
359.059
1.88235
358.088
0.97166
0.983607
354.958

Comment: Oh ok, I get you. To calculate the s.d. given the mean, follow eg [these instructions](http://www.mathsrevision.net/gcse/pages.php?page=42) (warning: Comic Sans :p)

Comment: Here's a link to a page on google books concerning standard deviation in circular data and the von Mises distribution: http://books.google.com/books?id=wGPj3EoFdJwC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22standard+deviation%22+circular+quantities&source=bl&ots=PiYoAyzGO6&sig=kgjr6mEz1znibEfW2-Xp94iAStY&hl=en&ei=XH3FTrPIJcObtwfP5pCmCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22standard%20deviation%22%20circular%20quantities&f=false

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simple solution is to convert those angles to a set of vectors, from polar coordinates into cartesian coordinates.

Since you are working with colors, think of this as a conversion into the (a*,b*) plane. Then take the mean of those coordinates, and then revert back into polar form again. Done in matlab,

```
theta = [355,5,5,5,5];
x = cosd(theta); % cosine in terms of degrees
y = sind(theta); % sine with a degree argument
```

Now, take the mean of x and y, compute the angle, then
convert back from radians to degrees.

```
meanangle = atan2(mean(y),mean(x))*180/pi
meanangle =
       3.0049
```

Of course, this solution is valid only for the mean angle. As you can see, it yields a consistent result with the mean of the angles directly, where I recognize that 355 degrees really wraps to -5 degrees.

```
mean([-5 5 5 5 5])
ans =
     3
```

To compute the standard deviation, it is simplest to do it as

```
std([-5 5 5 5 5])
ans =
       4.4721
```

Yes, that requires me to do the wrap explicitly.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes the standard deviation calculations must always take into account the wrap, whether at 0, red, in degrees or at Pi and negative Pi, a blue green, in radians.  Approaches for characterizing circular data other than std exist as well.  See links above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method proposed by user85109 is a good way to compute the mean, but not the standard deviation:
imagine to have three angles: 180, 180, 181

the mean would be correctly computed, as a number aproximately equal to 180

but from [180,180,-179] you would compute a high variance when in fact it is near zero

At first glance, I would compute separately the means and variances for the half positive angles , [0 to 180] and fot the negative ones [0,-180] and later I would compute the combined variance
https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/combined-variance.html

taking into account that the global mean and the difference between it and the local means has to be computed in both directions: clockwise and counterclockwise, and the the correct one has to be chosen.