# Calculate mean of hue angles

Tags: python, numpy

I have been struggling with this for some time, despite there being related questions on SO (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491738/how-do-you-calculate-the-average-of-a-set-of-angles)).

```
def circmean(arr):
    arr = np.deg2rad(arr)
    return np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(np.mean(np.sin(arr)),np.mean(np.cos(arr))))
```

But the results I'm getting don't make sense! I regularly get negative values, e.g.:

```
test = np.array([323.64,161.29])
circmean(test)
>> -117.53500000000004
```

I don't know if (a) my function is incorrect, (b) the method I'm using is incorrect, or (c) I just have to do a transformation to the negative values (add 360 degrees?). My research suggests that the problem isn't (a), and I've seen implementations (e.g. [here](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/ptweir/circular%20mean%20and%20variance)) matching my own, so I'm leaning towards (c), but I really don't know.

Comment: Since angles repeat, it doesn't matter if the range is 0 to 360 or -180 to 180, and evidently numpy selects the latter. Just add 360 to the negatives if that's the range you require.

Comment: Hmm...if it's the case that numpy is giving me values in the range -180 to 180, wouldn't I want to add 180 to *all* the values to get them in the 0-360 range?

Comment: No, because adding 180 changes the actual angle whereas adding 360 does not. You could also do `(angle + 360) % 360` instead of checking for negative. Edit: apparently just `angle % 360` works too.

Comment: @MarkRansom you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25942533/3903832), I've done some research that led me to find the `circmean` function in the [`scipy` library](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/index.html).
Considering you're using the `numpy` library, I thought that a proper implementation in the `scipy` library shall suit your needs.

As noted in my answer to the aforementioned question, I haven't found any documentation of that function, but inspecting its [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/morestats.py) revealed the proper way it should be invoked:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> 
>>> test = np.array([323.64,161.29])
>>> stats.circmean(test, high=360)
242.46499999999995
>>> 
>>> test = np.array([5, 350])
>>> stats.circmean(test, high=360)
357.49999999999994
```

This might not be of any use to you, since some time passed since you posted your question and considering you've already implemented the function yourself, but I hope it may benefit future readers who are struggling with the same issue.